# Determining type of a void* (and other variables) in C

Tags: c, lisp, void-pointers

I am writing a simple Lisp interpreter and have the following `struct`s and `enum`s defined:

```c
typedef enum {
    STRING,
    INTEGER,
    FLOAT,
    FUNCTION,
    VARIABLE,
    SYMBOL,
    NIL
} atom_e;

typedef union {
    char* string;
    int integer;
    float decimal;
} data_t;

typedef struct {
    data_t data;
    atom_e type;
    void* next;
} atom_t;

typedef struct {
    void* head;
} list_t;
```

`atom_e` refers to the supported atom types for my Lisp.
`data_t` is used to store each atom. It is only ever used in `atom_t`.
`list_t` is used to collect `atom_t`s. It has `head` which points to either an
`atom_t` or a `list_t` (in the case of nested lists)
`atom_t` is the struct for an atom. It consists of an atom (stored in `data`)
, a description of its type (`type`), and a `void*`. This void pointer may point to another `atom_t` or a `list_t`.

I designed it this way in order to make more clear when writing the Lisp when a
list is nested and what its parent/child list is. Parsing a s-exp will always give
you a list_t* because all valid Lisp code begins with an opening bracket, the sign of a list starting.

I'm at the "eval" stage of the Lisp now, and the `eval` function works as follows:

If `next` (in an `atom_t` or a `list_t`) points to an `atom_t`, `eval` that atom and the ones that follow (ie. `(set x 10)`).
If `next` points to a `list_t`, eval that entire list, atom by atom.(ie. "(set x (* 5 2))")

I designed it as described above assuming that C provides a built-in `type()` or `isinstance()` function that I could use in the `eval` function - to the best of my knowledge, it doesn't. How would I mimic the function of Python's `isinstance()` in C, so that I can compare types of void pointers? I'd like to stick to ANSI C where possible, at the latest C99, in order to maximise portability.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reflection in C - meaning you can't reason with the language types of variables at runtime the same way you can in Python.

What you *can* do is store the type of element inside its struct - e.g.

```
typedef enum {
    DATA,
    ATOM
} element_type;
```

and

```
typedef union {
    element_type type;
    ...
} data_t;

typedef struct {
    element_type type;
    ...
} atom_t;
```

and then check it like this:

```
void* element;
element_type type = *((element_type*)element);
if (type == DATA) {
    data_t* data = (data_t*)element;
    ....
} else if (type == ATOM) {
    atom_t* atom = (atom_t*)element;
    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can have a single struct that encapsulates both a type and a `void*`:

```
struct {
    element_type type;
    void* element; // points to data_t* or atom_t* depending on the type
}
```

---

Bonus fun fact - this is a common pattern in C codebases, with one of the most famous examples found in Python itself. All objects in CPython are C [`PyObjects`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/object.h#L109) behind the scenes:

```
typedef struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
} PyObject;
```

and CPython looks at the `ob_type` field to know which type a generic `PyObject` is.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to do this:

```
typedef enum {
    STRING,
    INTEGER,
    FLOAT,
    FUNCTION,
    VARIABLE,
    SYMBOL,
    LIST,  // Add this!
    NIL
} atom_e;
```

Then in `data_t` add this:

```
typedef union {
    char* string;
    int integer;
    float decimal;
    void *head; // add this, specific to LIST type
} data_t;
```

Thereby, the list is just another `atom_t`.  Of course, then this type should not be called `atom_t` but `value_t` or something like that: it represents any value: atoms as well as list.

The `atom_e` should just be `type_e`: it enumerates all types, not only atoms.

Your eval function then has to do

```
switch (value->type) {
case STRING:
case INTEGER:
case FLOAT:
case FUNCTION:
case NIL:
  return value; // these are self-evaluating
case VARIABLE:
  // ?
case SYMBOL:
  // ?
case LIST:
  // implement compound form evaluation here
}
```

So there is your `instanceof`; you just look at the type code you already have.

Note that real Lisp doesn't have "variable" and "symbol" as distinct types. A variable is an association between a symbol and a value, not a kind of object. When a symbol is evaluated, it is understood to be a variable: the evaluator searches the current environment for a binding which is named by that symbol.

(A Lisp environment could be a collection of binding objects that are internally of type `VARIABLE`, for doing run-time indirection on variables, but that's an extension over basic Lisp semantics.)